# Multiple subqueries on the same field with activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, subquery

In activerecord, preferably without literal sql, I'm trying to get roughly this going:

```
Thing.where(:id => Link.select(:col1).where(subquery1), :id => Link.select(:col2).where(subquery2))
```

I need it to give me an AND between the subqueries, but instead the last subquery overrides the preceding ones.

Note: I'm selecting a different column from the Link table in each subquery

I've already tried this:

```
t = Thing.where(:id => Link.where(subquery1))
t.where(:id => Link.where(subquery2))
```

Also note the nature of the subqueries mean I can't put my AND into a single subquery

Any way to do this in ActiveRecord without resorting to SQL?

I'm using Rails 3 and PostgreSQL

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off chaining two where conditions then combining them.

```
Thing.where(:id => Link.select(:col1).where(subquery1)).where(:id => Link.select(:col2).where(subquery2))
```

This will add the `AND` between the two `IN` queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work - see I'm also selecting a different Link column in each subquery. I'll update the question

Comment: @whalabi I updated my answer, does this solution still not solve your problem, if not can you explain why